# Adding a script CHtml::textField() method

Tags: php, yii

I have following code:

```
echo CHtml::textField('car_type_title');
```

and it outputs:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="car_type_title" id="car_type_title">
```

I want onchange it to perform some script. I could do it like this:

```
echo CHtml::textField('car_type_title') . 
"<script>
    $('#car_type_title').on('change', function(){
       alert('');
 });
</script>";
```

Is there a way to add a parameter with to CHtml::textFied(), that would call a function? I cant figure those htmlOptions..

FOUND SOLUTION:

```
CHtml::textField('car_type_title', '', array('onchange'=>'javascript:alert("Here we go!")');
```

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer below and mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::textField('car_type_title', '', array('onchange'=>'getAlert()'));
?>

<script>
    function getAlert(){
        alert('Here we go!');
    }
</script>
```